# Azure Old Portal Virtual Machine Remote Connect Login Failure

Tags: windows, azure, remote-desktop

I am a Microsoft Azure New Preview portal user. I am thinking to run Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. I will use my virtual machine to support Boinc Grid Project.

I've added Microsoft Windows Server to my Microsoft Azure. But, I couldn't connect to my Microsoft Azure's remote desktop. It gives login failure. I have tried my Microsoft Azure password and Windows Server Account's password. But, It didn't change...

I didn't try to connect on Microsoft PowerShell. I have taken notes about my protocols, private ports and website names. If they needs, I can give them.

Can you please help me to connect remote desktop.

Btw, my virtual machine website is;

> boincgrid.cloudapp.net

Waiting your help, have a nice and Ideaflow days.

**Edited at 22.6.2019 after using instruction by @Tom Van Gramberen**

I had followed your given instructions. But, I stacked in one step;

I finished all instruction in http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/04/03/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx. But, after connected to my Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine, I couldn't Get-AzureVM...

My output in PowerShell is;

```
PS C:\> Get-Module Azure

PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

PS C:\> Import-Module Azure

PS C:\> Add-AzureAccount

PS C:\> Get-AzureSubsription | Format-Table -Property SubsriptionName
Get-AzureSubsription : The term 'Get-AzureSubsription' is not recognized as the name of a cm
dlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pa
th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureSubsription | Format-Table -Property SubsriptionName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureSubsription:String) [], CommandNotF 
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureSubscription | Format-Table -Property SubscriptionName

SubscriptionName                                                                            
----------------                                                                            
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               
Pay-As-You-Go                                                                               



PS C:\> $subsription = "Pay-As-You-Go"

PS C:\> Select-AzureSubscription -Default $subscription
Select-AzureSubscription : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubscriptionName'. The arg
ument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the comm
and again.
At line:1 char:35
+ Select-AzureSubscription -Default $subscription
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ParameterBinding 
   ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Comma 
   nds.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand
 

PS C:\> Select-AzureSubscription -Default $subscription
Select-AzureSubscription : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubscriptionName'. The arg
ument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the comm
and again.
At line:1 char:35
+ Select-AzureSubscription -Default $subscription
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ParameterBinding 
   ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Comma 
   nds.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand
 

PS C:\> $subscription = “ENTER YOUR SUBSCRIPTION NAME HERE”
 
Select-AzureSubscription –Default $subscription
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription named 'ENTER YOUR SUBSCRIPTION NAME HERE' cannot
 be found. Use Set-AzureSubscription to initialize the subscription data.
At line:3 char:1
+ Select-AzureSubscription –Default $subscription
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscripti 
   onCommand
 

PS C:\> $subscription = “Pay-As-You-Go”
 
Select-AzureSubscription –Default $subscription

PS C:\> $adminCredentials = Get-Credential -Message "Message new Admin credentals"

PS C:\> 
Get-AzureVM | 
Where-Object -Property Status -EQ "ReadyRole" |
Out-GridView -Title "Select a VM …" -PassThru |
ForEach-Object {
    $VM = Get-AzureVM -Name $_.Name -ServiceName $_.ServiceName
    If ($VM.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent) {
        Set-AzureVMAccessExtension -VM $VM `
            -UserName $adminCredentials.UserName `
            -Password $adminCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password `
            -ReferenceName "VMAccessAgent" | 
        Update-AzureVM
        Restart-AzureVM -ServiceName $VM.ServiceName -Name $VM.Name
    } else {
        Write-Output "$($VM.Name): VM Agent Not Installed"
    }
}

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" ' | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" ' | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus";
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" ' | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" ' | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus";
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" ' | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"}
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'boincgrid'.

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "VIRTUAL MACHINES" -Name "BoincGrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
Get-AzureVm : BadRequest: The hosted service name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "VIRTUAL MACHINES" -Name "BoincGrid" | Format-Table -au ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzu 
   reVMCommand
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "VIRTUAL MACHINE" -Name "BoincGrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
Get-AzureVm : BadRequest: The hosted service name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "VIRTUAL MACHINE" -Name "BoincGrid" | Format-Table -aut ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzu 
   reVMCommand
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "Virtual Machine" -Name "BoincGrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
Get-AzureVm : BadRequest: The hosted service name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "Virtual Machine" -Name "BoincGrid" | Format-Table -aut ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzu 
   reVMCommand
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "VIRTUAL MACHINE" -Name "boincgrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
Get-AzureVm : BadRequest: The hosted service name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "VIRTUAL MACHINE" -Name "boincgrid" | Format-Table -aut ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzu 
   reVMCommand
 

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "Boincgrid" -Name "boincgrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'Boincgrid'.

PS C:\> Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" -Name "boincgrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'boincgrid'.

PS C:\>
```

My Virtual Machine and Cloud Service name is BoincGrid.

I've edited their given command in Microsoft Developer Network...

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495236.aspx

Their example command is:

```
Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "MySvc1" ' | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
```

My edited command is;

```
Get-AzureVm -ServiceName "boincgrid" -Name "boincgrid" | Format-Table -auto "Name",@{Expression={$_.InstanceUpgradeDomain};Label="UpgDom";Align="Right"},"InstanceStatus"
```

And the output is;

> WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'boincgrid'.

I couldn't connect my virtual machine.

Comment: If you can login to Management Portal , then you can change the Password for RDP. Service -> Configure -> Remote(On bottom) -> Give the new password.

Comment: sudhAnsu63, I couldn't find where to change password of RDP Service.
I am using old portal and I couldn't find Service section in Azure portal. 
I think it is hard to change password of RDP in Old portal. 
Thanks.

Comment: @sarialp_mustafa, I installed BOINC on my Azure VM but it never connects to grab new units.  Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a login failure I can only suggest to verify the username and password you are using to connect.

In case you no longer remember the correct password, it can be reset using PowerShell. Simply follow the procedure described here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/04/03/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx (Note: it requires the VM Agent to be installed in the Virtual Machine).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps on New Azure management Portal for changing password.
I have no longer access to Old Portal, so Providing help on New One.
I think you can switch to New Portal.

[image: Step 1& 2 Choose your Service]
[image: Step 3 Configure]
[image: Step 4 Choose Remote Option]
[image: Step 5 Change Password Here]

Comment: I tried new preview portal and it says I have to use old full portal for virtual machines.

Comment: I tried new preview portal and it says I have to use old-full portal for virtual machines.
@sudhAnsu63 you suggest to add new remote desktop, or configure it again with new password. But I couldn't find where should I do it. I can't find Configure Remote Desktop window. Can you help me how can I open this Remote Desktop configuration windows. It seems, the system has bugs for RDP passwords. 
Nice ideaflow days.